# Intel UHD 770 on Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 no /dev/dri

Tags: drivers, server, intel-graphics, intel

I've installed **Ubuntu Server LTS 20.04.3** (**5.4.0-97**-generic) on my home server, that has an [Intel 12th 12500T](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/96140/intel-core-i512500t-processor-18m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz.html). This CPU has included graphics **Intel® UHD Graphics 770**.

But I notice I cannot find the **/dev/dri** that can be used for hardware acceleration like transcoding etc.

I also tried to install **intel-media-va-driver-non-free** from [intel repositories](https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.html) but still no success.

I know this is a very recent CPU/GPU, but anybody had face similar issue and find some kind of solution?

Comment: Hardware is too new > kernel too old.